# jq select with variable that has colon

Tags: jq

I have the following test.json file

```
{
"name": "value1:value2",
"StartDate": "2015-09-01T04:00:00Z",
"EndDate": "2016-09-05T09:59:59Z"
}
```

The following jq command works on command line:

```
jq 'select(.name=="value1:value2") | .EndDate' test.json
```

However, if I try to execute same command in my bash script with a variable i.e.

```
var="value1:value2"
endDateVar=$(jq "select(.name==""${var}") | .EndDate" test.json)
```

I get the following error:

```
error: syntax error, unexpected ':'
select(.name==value1:value2) | .EndDate                                            1 compile error
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Always use the `--arg` (or `--argjson`) switch to pass in shell variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many possibilities, some better than others.  Here's a reasonable approach, assuming you have a Mac or Linux-like shell:

```
$ var="value1:value2"
$ jq --arg var "$var" 'select(.name==$var) | .EndDate' test.json
"2016-09-05T09:59:59Z"
```

To see more clearly what's going on, here is an equivalent invocation:

```
$ jq --arg v "$var" 'select(.name==$v) | .EndDate' test.json
```

Your approach can of course also be made to work, e.g.

```
$ jq "select(.name==\"""${var}""\") | .EndDate" test.json
"2016-09-05T09:59:59Z"
```

but as you've already seen, it's easy to get lost in the tangle of backslashes and quotation marks.

Comment: Use `--arg`. The last approach may look like you are "passing" a variable, but you are really just generating dynamic code. Specifically, it will work until oops, the value of `$var` contained a character that `jq` treats as part of its syntax, then your code breaks.

Comment: I totally wasn't aware of the `--arg` option. Thanks.